# Гнуть, погибель и сгинуть

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Считаются ли глаголы *гнуть, гибнуть, сгинуть* однокоренными?

Answer (score 3):

Да, эти слова, похоже, этимологически однокоренные. Возможно, разобраться и убедиться в этом Вам помогут ссылки на статьи, из которых я взяла такую информацию:

Глагол **гнуть** в настоящее время имеет семантику воздействия на объект, а согласная суффикса -Н-, по-видимому, уже входит в его корень. Этимологически же этот глагол, как указывает М.Фасмер, тождественен глаголу **гибнуть**, оба эти глагола имели корень ***gyb** (ср.сгибать). Один из вариантов сохранил и корень, и суффикс, а другой пережил сильную редукцию старого корня, изменил семантику, а след суффикса -НУ- сохранил. Может быть, и не случайно просторечный глагол **загнуться** имеет и семему **умереть**. [Суффикс -ну-](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/suffiks-66819.html)

Ги́бнуть **ги́нуть**, укр. ги́нути, ги́бнути, ст.-слав. гыбнѫти, болг. ги́на, сербохорв. ги̏нути, словен. gíniti, чеш. hynouti, польск. ginąć, в.-луж. hinyć, нж.-луж. ginuś. Праслав. *gyb- «гибнуть» и *gyb- «гнуть» едины в этимологическом отношении, вопреки Миклошичу (Mi. EW 82), Бецценбергеру (ВВ 4, 352 и др.); см. Бернекер 1, 373 и сл. Ср. лтш. gubt, gubstu «гнуться, никнуть», лит. gaũbti «выгибать, делать выпуклым», возм., также англос. géap «согнутый, искривленный», géopan «поглощать», греч. κύπτω, κέκυφε «горбиться, гнуться», κῦφος «изгиб, горб». [Словарь Фасмера](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%B3/%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)